# excel changing formula when I move source data - lock and protect sheet not working

Tags: vba, excel, locking, protected

I have this spreadsheet that has a Master page and a Weekly page for reporting. The weekly page is supposed to pull off of a range of the first 5 columns of data from the master sheet.

Problem is when I run the macro to add a new column (shift data to the right and create a new column on the left) all my formulas change to follow the data that just moved right.

Ex: Data on the Weekly sheet is set with a formula that reads the value from D2 on the Master sheet. When I add the new column at the master sheet this changes to E2 even if I use $E$2.

What can I do to prevent this from happening?

This is using Office 2013 with Service Pack 1 installed.

This is the code used for moving the data:

```
ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=30
Range("A43:A62").Select
Selection.Copy
ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=-66
Range("D2").Select
Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight
Range("D2").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[1]+7"
Range("D2").Select
Selection.Copy
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a way to keep the reference from shifting over when you insert cells like that. So the only way I know of to keep your Master sheet referencing cell D2 would be to use the macro to reenter the formula on the master sheet after the cells have been added to the weekly report.

Try something like this:

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim ms As Worksheet

Set ws = Worksheets("Weekly Report")
Set ms = Worksheets("Master Report")

'Your other code goes here

ms.Range("A1") = "=" & ws.Name & "$D$2"
```

This assumes A1 is the cell on your master sheet that references D2.

Comment: I tried this, but with how I had the data laid out I ended up just doing a simple copy function on the reference page to display my most recent set of data. This way I skipped what looked like it would have been a much more complex script. Thanks for the response though